# Using regexp to find a reoccurring pattern in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, strsplit

```
 input = ' 12Z taj 20501 jfdjda OCNL jtjajd ptpa 23Z jfdakdkf tjajdfk OCNL fdkadja 02Z fdjafsdk fkdsafk OCNL fdkafk dksakj = '
```

using regexp

```
regexp(input,'\s\d{2,4}Z\s.*(OCNL)','match')
```

I'm trying to get the output

[1,1] = `12Z taj 20501 jfdjda OCNL jtjajd ptpa`

[1,2] = `23Z jfdakdkf tjajdfk OCNL fdkadja`

[1,3] = `02Z fdjafsdk fkdsafk OCNL fdkafk dksakj`

Comment: What is the trailing boundary pattern of the expected match? It does not look like `OCNL` is the trailing boundary.

Comment: Add `?` to `\s\d{2,4}Z\s.*?(OCNL)`

Comment: @ran_0315 The lazy quantifier itself does not yield the expected results.

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)\d{2,4}Z\s.*?\S(?=(?:\s\d{2,4}Z\s|\s*=\s*$))` pattern.

Comment: @John You have asked three regex questions to which you have received answers. Please provide feedback to those people who are trying to help you out.

Comment: I will try both ways Wiktor.

Comment: This method (?<!\S)\d{2,4}Z\s.*?\S(?=(?:\s\d{2,4}Z\s|\s*=\s*$)) work perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)\d{2,4}Z\s+.*?\S(?=\s\d{2,4}Z\s|\s*=\s*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n5iiVn/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - there must be a whitespace or start of string immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{2,4}` - 2, 3 or 4 digits
- `Z` - a `Z` letter
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `.*?\S`  - any zero or more chars as few as possible and then a non-whitespace
- `(?=\s\d{2,4}Z\s|\s*=\s*$)` - there must be either of the two patterns immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `\s\d{2,4}Z\s` - a whitespace, 2, 3 or 4 digits, `Z` and a whitespace
  - `|` - or
  - `\s*=\s*$` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars at the end of the string.